# Making basic calculator in java and having trouble with input validation methods

Tags: java

I am in school for Java and the current assignment I have is slowly building a calculator. the teacher uploaded the wrong lectures on the current part and I can't find a solution to my problem. so I have my main method where input is handled and the input is passed to two functions. one validates that real numbers were entered, and the second function validates that the numbers are separated by a valid operator (^ * / + -). I figured out the number validation but I don't know how to validate the operator in the string. The input string must be validated before the main function changes the input in to an array and continues. here is my code so far

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> validOperators = new ArrayList<String>(){{
            add("^");
            add("*");
            add("/");
            add("+");
            add("-");
        }};
        System.out.println("This is a text based calculator!");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);        
        boolean loop = true;
        while (loop) {
            System.out.println("Enter a math expression ot type quit to exit: ");
            String math = in.nextLine();
            if ("quit".equalsIgnoreCase(math)) {
                System.out.print("Quitting");
                break;
            }
            
             if (isOperator(math)){
                 String[] splitExpression = math.split("\\s+");
                 if (isNumber(splitExpression)){
                    for (int i=0; i<splitExpression.length; i++){
                        System.out.println(splitExpression[i]);
                    } 
                    System.out.println("Number of tokens: " + splitExpression.length);
                 }else {
                     System.out.println("invalid expression!");
                 }
             }else{
                 System.out.println("please use valid operators");
             }
            
            
        }
    }
    public static boolean isNumber(String[] number){
        try {
            double test = Double.parseDouble(number[0]);
            double test2 = Double.parseDouble(number[2]);
        } catch (Exception e){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public static boolean isOperator(String operator){
        if (operator.contains("^")){
            return true;
        }else{
        return false;
        }
        
    }
    public static boolean isValidExpression(String[] strArray){
        String strOfArray = Arrays.toString(strArray);
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isOperator()` is checking for exponential operator, you may need to check for `addition(+), substration(-), multiplication(*) ,division(/) and modulo(%)`

**isOperator**

```
public static boolean isAnOperator(char c) {
    switch (c) {
        case '*':
        case '/':
        case '+':
        case '-':
        case '%':
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

**update isANumber to check if given charater of string is a number**

```
public static boolean isANumber(char c){
    return ((int)c) >= 48 && ((int)c) <= 57;
}
```

**isValidExpression()**

```
public static boolean isValidExpression(String expression) {
    if (isAnOperator(expression.charAt(0)) || isAnOperator(expression.charAt(expression.length() - 1))) {
        return false;
    }

    int openParenthCount = 0;
    boolean lastWasOp = false;
    boolean lastWasOpen = false;

    for (char c : expression.toCharArray()) {
        if(c == ' ') continue;
        if (c == '(') {
            openParenthCount++;
            lastWasOpen = true;
            continue;
        } else if (c == ')') {
            if (openParenthCount <= 0 || lastWasOp) {
                return false;
            }
            openParenthCount--;
        }else if (isAnOperator(c)){
            if (lastWasOp || lastWasOpen) return false;
            lastWasOp = true;
            continue;
        }else if(!isANumber(c)){
            return false;
        }
        lastWasOp = false;
        lastWasOpen = false;
    }
    if(openParenthCount != 0) return false;
    if(lastWasOp || lastWasOpen) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Your code helped me a lot but I was going through my rubric and realized one of the requirements is that isValidExpression must take (String[] expression) instead of just String expression. would the code still be similar even though its taking the input as an array now?